# ManipulationMode explained

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, uwp, winrt-xaml, uwp-xaml

Can someone explain the meaning of [manipulation modes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.input.manipulationmodes) such as `TranslateX`, `TranslateRailsX`, `TranslateInertia` ?
What is a `rail mode`? And what inertia they are talking about?

Comment: I think that API is in WinRT/XAML only and not WPF, so I removed the WPF tag from your question and added the windows runtime one for clarity.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With rails - when the input processor detects whether the manipulation is mostly vertical or mostly horizontal it sticks to the respective axis when reporting translation delta/cumulative values. If not - it just allows to freely manipulate whatever you are manipulating. Rails flags have to be used in combination with the non-rails flags, so just `TranslateRailsX` doesn't work. You need both that and `TranslateX` to get anything going.

The `TranslateInertia` flag allows for simple handling for flicks or inertial rotations/scales in case of the other inertia flags. Basically if you add that flag to the `TranslateX` one for example and you do a quick flick gesture - you will keep getting the input events (`ManipulationDelta`) for a while even after the gesture is completed. You also get the `ManipulationInertiaStarting` event when you flick once the input stream ends, so you get to control how far the flick goes if you want to. You can check out [my extensions](https://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#WinRTXamlToolkit/Controls/Extensions/ManipulationInertiaStartingRoutedEventArgsExtensions.cs) to the argument of that event in WinRT XAML Toolkit to get some more control over the ballistics of the flick too.

Your `ManipulationDeltaEventArgs` have an `IsIntertial` property you can also use to check if the events you are getting are directly from input events or a result of a flick and also call `Complete()` if for some reason you don't want to continue getting the delta events for the flick.

Comment: If you need both TranslateRailsX and TranslateX, then how come the msdn doc says: "Don't combine Translate* values with TranslateRails* values, these are treated as mutually exclusive values"? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.manipulationmode

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example that shows how I implemented TranslateRailsX/Y.

I wanted it to only register horizontal swipe but with just using TranslateX/Y it was picking up the left or right even if I was just swiping up or down.

So just a simple XAML and as in my instance I only want horizontal swipes not the vertical swipes.

xaml file:

```
<Grid Background="WhiteSmoke">
     <WebView Name="webview" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
</Grid>
```

xaml.cs file:

```
    int x1;
    int x2;
    int y1;
    int y2;
public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        webview.ManipulationMode = ManipulationModes.TranslateRailsX |  ManipulationModes.TranslateRailsY;
        webview.ManipulationStarted += (s, e) => x1 = (int)e.Position.X;
        webview.ManipulationStarted += (s, e) => y1 = (int)e.Position.Y;

        webview.ManipulationCompleted += (s, e) =>
        {
            x2 = (int)e.Position.X;
            y2 = (int)e.Position.Y;

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(x1);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(x2);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(y1);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(y2);

            if (x1  > x2)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("right");
            };
            if (x1 < x2 )
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("left");

            }

        };
```

And now I get the following on a vertical swipe

```
x1 180 
x2 180  
y1 201  
y2 386
```

And horizontal swipe

```
 x1 89
 x2 293
 y1 371
 y2 371
 left or right
```

Hope this helps someone in the same predicament.